# Почему не сохраняются пути к картинкам в базе данных?

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, сохраняю картинки.

На диск, в нужный каталог и под нужным именем копируются нормально, но в базу не сохраняются. Почему так?
Контроллер:

```
 public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new Products();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        if ($model->create()) {
            if ($model->save()){
                $model->loadImages();
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Метод для загрузки:

```
public function loadImages(){
    $this->image =  UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'image');
    if ($this->image && $this->validate()){
        $dir = "uploads/products/$this->name";
        if(!file_exists($dir)){
            mkdir($dir);
            chmod($dir, 1777);
        }
        foreach ($this->image as $i => $images){
            $model = new Images();
            $model->name =  "$dir/$i.$images->extension";
            $model->save();
            $model->num = $i;
            $model->users_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $model->products_id = $model->id;
            $images->saveAs($model->name);
        }
    }
}
```

Представление (ничего особенного, только поля формы):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'price')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'bar_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'vendor_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'count')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'fabricators_id')->dropDownList(Fabricators::getParam('name')) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку: проблема была в моей невнимательности.

```
$model->products_id = $model->id;
```

должно было быть

```
$model->products_id = $this->id
```

Поля у модели картинок - **required**, а т.к. products_id получал пустое значение (модель не сохранена, в базе автоинкрементация), то и сохранять картинки она не собиралась.

Помогло использование **var_dump**

Вот так выглядит рабочий код (может кому-нибудь будет интересно...):

```
public function loadImages(){
    $this->image =  UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'image');
    if ($this->image && $this->validate()){
        $dir = "uploads/products/$this->name";
        foreach ($this->image as $i => $images){
            $model = new Images();
            $model->name = "$dir/$i.$images->extension";
            $model->num = $i;
            $model->users_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $model->products_id = $this->id;
            if($model->save()){
                if(!file_exists($dir)){
                    mkdir($dir);
                    chmod($dir, 1777);
                }
                $images->saveAs($model->name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Замени на:
$model->name =  "$dir/$i.".$images->extension;

в базе ещё тип данных на поле name - надо text поставить

Comment: чем плох varchar? и нет, к сожалению это не сработало. тут что-то другое.

Comment: если бы проблема была в этом, то и картинки бы не сохранялись, и директория бы не создавалась.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $model = new Images();
        $model->name =  "$dir/$i.$images->extension";
        $model->save();
        $model->num = $i;
        $model->users_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $model->products_id = $model->id;
        $images->saveAs($model->name);
```

А это нормально не проверять сохранилась ли модель, и сохранять ее перед тем, как запишешь в нее все?

Всегда проверяйте перед сохранением

```
if($model->save(){} 
else{// отлов ошибок}
```

Comment: проверял, почему не сохраняется, забыл убрать.